# Does iBatis supports lazy loading like Hibernate?

Tags: lazy-loading, ibatis

I wanted to know whether iBatis can provide support for lazy fetch just like Hibernate supports? For example I have User class which has

```
public class User {
    List<Address> addresses;

    public List<Address> getAddresses(){
        return addresses;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I wanted to implement the lazy fetching when user.getAddresses() is called. Is it possible to achieve this in iBatis? If yes then how?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.
According to documentation, you can set the `lazyLoad` attribute of the `result` element of a `resultMap` for the property you want to be lazy loaded.
E.g.:

```
<resultMap id="resultMapUser" class="User">
    <result property="addresses" select="someOtherStatementName" lazyLoad="true"/>
</resultMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML mapping:
3.2.7+ -> fetchType attribute (lazy/eager)

```
<resultMap id="itemResultMap" type="Item">
    <id property="id" column="id"/>
    <association property="subItem" column="subItemId" javaType="SubItem" 
                 select="selectSubItemByIdQuery" fetchType="lazy"/>
</resultMap>
```

@Annotation mapping:

```
@Select({"SELECT * FROM item WHERE id = #{id}"})
@Results({
        @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
        @Result(property = "subItem", column = "subItemId", javaType = SubItem.class,
                one = @One(select = "SubItemMapper.getById", 
                           fetchType = FetchType.LAZY))
})
Item getById(int id);
```